# Table align in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a two part question, I have searched under multiple tags to find an answer to no avail.

I have a table containing 4 columns and 4 nuggets, I am trying to get them to auto align on the page load so that the four columns take the whole width of the page across the bottom. I would like it to look the same whether the user is on a 22" wide screen or a 15" screen:

1. Would this best be done by JavaScript or is there a more efficient
   way of doing this?
2. How would you achieve this?

Edit: sorry I should have been more specific, this is my code:

```
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:#c1bdb6;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" id="col-1">
                            <div id="nugget1" align="right" style="height: 459px;">
                                <div id="nugget1-content" align="left">
                                    <h2 class="menutitle"> FAQ's </h2>

                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" id="col-2">
                            <div id="nugget2" align="center" style="height: 459px;">
                                <h2 class="menutitle"> Contacts </h2>
                            </div>
                      </td>                                    
                      <td valign="top" id="col-3">
                            <div id="nugget3" align="center" style="height: 459px;">
                                 <h2 class="menutitle"> Calendar </h2>
                                    <ul class="vertmenu">  
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5F5v1EYaSTA"> Shared Calendars </a>
                                        </li>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" id="col-4">
                             <div id="nugget4" align="center" style="height: 459px;">
                                 <h2 class="menutitle"> Mail </h2>
                             </div>
                      </td>

                  </tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>
```

Comment: What on earth is 'a nugget'? Also, what's your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there's a particular reason why you're using such outdated HTML (tables for layout, use of things like `valign` and `align` in the HTML, etc), the most efficient (with regards to page load) way of achieving what you want is by restructuring your HTML to something more along the lines of:

```
<div id="nuggets">
  <div id="nugget1">
    <h2 class="menutitle"> FAQ's </h2>
  </div> 
  <div id="nugget2" class="col">
     <h2 class="menutitle"> Contacts </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="nugget3">
     <h2 class="menutitle"> Calendar </h2>
     <ul class="vertmenu">  
       <li>
         <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5F5v1EYaSTA"> Shared Calendars </a>
       </li>
  </div>
  <div id="nugget4">
    <h2 class="menutitle"> Mail </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then have CSS along the lines of:

```
#nuggets {
  height: 459px;
}

#nuggets > div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 459px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a nugget is a table cell, this is probably what you're looking for:

1. This sounds like a job for CSS.
2. Relevant CSS:

   table {
     width: 100%;
   }

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the table width to correspond to screen resolution, perhaps using this ?

```
<table width="100%" height="100%">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle">
Body html here
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the actual HTML `<table>` tag for your table, then the easiest way to do it is with the `<colgroup>` tag.

In your case, the code would be:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:#c1bdb6;">
    <colgroup width="25%" />
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="top" id="col-1">
                <div id="nugget1" align="right" style="height: 459px;">
                    <div id="nugget1-content" align="left">
                        <h2 class="menutitle"> FAQ's </h2>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" id="col-2">
                <div id="nugget2" align="center" style="height: 459px;">
                    <h2 class="menutitle"> Contacts </h2>
                </div>
            </td>                                    
            <td valign="top" id="col-3">
                <div id="nugget3" align="center" style="height: 459px;">
                    <h2 class="menutitle"> Calendar </h2>
                    <ul class="vertmenu">  
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5F5v1EYaSTA"> Shared Calendars </a>
                        </li>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" id="col-4">
                <div id="nugget4" align="center" style="height: 459px;">
                    <h2 class="menutitle"> Mail </h2>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Any attributes in the `<colgroup>` will apply to all of the columns in that group.  If you have specific styling that you'd like to do to any of the individual columns, you can add `<col>` tags within the `<colgroup>` for each column, to define them.  You can also nest `<colgroup>` tags inside each other.

Comment: Updated with your original code . . . note, you are missing an closing `<ul>` tag.   ;)